# Numpy function that utilizes index as it iterates Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, iterator

How can I write a numpy code where it takes in the numpy array and then calculates the percentage of the arrays that are positive, it will do this until it reaches the end of the arrays. So as the code goes through index `a` for the first and second index the calculations will be `negative or positive value/index *100` so since 12 is positive it will be `1/1 * 100 = 100, 2/2 *100=100` until it reaches a negative value in the third index then it will be `2/3 * 100`. The percentage has gone down since now only 2 out of the 3 indexes checked were positive. How will I be able to do that and get the Expected Output below preferably without a for loop?

```
import numpy as np 

a = np.array([12, 23,-12 ,2 ,-1 ,-44, 8, -9, 1.45])
b = np.array([-12.2, -1.45, 0.74, -88])
```

Expected Output

```
[100, 100, 66.6, 75, 60, 50, 57.1, 50, 55.5]
[0, 0, 33.3, 25]
```

Comment: Show with a for loop

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(a > 0).cumsum() / np.arange(1, len(a)+1) * 100

array([100.        , 100.        ,  66.66666667,  75.        ,
        60.        ,  50.        ,  57.14285714,  50.        ,
        55.55555556])
```

`(a > 0).cumsum()` gives the running count of positives while `np.arange(1, len(a)+1)`  gives the running count of total elements. Dividing them gives the percentage.

Similar for `b`:

```
(b > 0).cumsum() / np.arange(1, len(b)+1) * 100
array([ 0.        ,  0.        , 33.33333333, 25.        ])
```